# Best way to re arrange array of object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have an array or object which will serve as columns for a table with a unique key

```
const list = [{
    key: "Name",
    textColor: "red"
  },{
    key: "Age",
    textColor: "green"
  },{
    key: "Occupation",
    textColor: "yellow"
}]
```

And, I have a list of ordering of columns in the table

```
const newOrder = ["Occupation", "Name", "Age"]
```

Now , how can i rearrange the list according to the newOrder without using `nested loops`. Also, these all are dyanamic, so its not just about the above mentioned three columns

Expected Output

```
const list = [{
    key: "Occupation",
    textColor: "yellow"
  },{
    key: "Name",
    textColor: "red"
  },{
    key: "Age",
    textColor: "green"
}]
```

Comment: can there be elements with duplicate key

Comment: At the moment the sort order is in reverse alphabetical order. O, N, A. Will that always be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list can be reformatted to a regular javascript object in which `key` is the property name, and `textColor` is the value:

```
const toObject = kvps => Object.fromEntries(kvps.map(kvp => [ kvp.key, kvp.textColor ]));
```

With a given array of keys, you can pick values from that object like so:

```js
const fromObject = (order, obj) => order.map(key => ({ key, textColor: obj[key] }));
```

Chain the two together, and you can reorder any list of key value pairs:

```js
const list = [{
    key: "Name",
    textColor: "red"
  },{
    key: "Age",
    textColor: "green"
  },{
    key: "Occupation",
    textColor: "yellow"
}]


const toObject = kvps => Object.fromEntries(kvps.map(kvp => [ kvp.key, kvp.textColor ]));
const fromObject = (order, obj) => order.map(key => ({ key, textColor: obj[key] }));
const reorder = (order, kvps) => fromObject(order, toObject(kvps));


const newList = reorder(["Occupation", "Name", "Age"], list);

console.log(
  newList
)
```

<sub>Edit: if the sizes of your list and order arrays are small, you probably want to go with the much easier to read approach suggested by Jon Webb in one of the other answers.  I tried to keep my solution to an O(n + m) complexity rather than O(n * m), (n = list size, m = order size) but it's probably not worth the added complexity.</sub>

Comment: This is the less complexity solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate on the "order" list, finding the corresponding item in the original list, and push the item to the new list in that order:

```js
const orderList = (list, order) => {
  const newList = [];

  for (key of order) {
    const item = list.find((obj) => obj.key == key);
    if (item) newList.push(item);
  }

  return newList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sort method on the array. The sort method will sort *in place* so you should copy your array if you dont want to mutate the original.

The array `sort` method takes a compare function the receives two elements for comparison `a` and `b`. It should return a number and it will sort them depending on that number:

- If `> 0` then `b` is before `a`
- If `< 0` then `b` is after `a`
- If `0` then keep as is

By using `indexOf` on the `newOrder` array can get the index of the key. And index of 0 should come before and index of 1 should come before and index of 2 of course. So if the index of `a.key` is 2 and the index of `b.key` is 0, then we should return a value greater than 0 since `b` should come before `a`.

In my implementation below I'm cloning the original list (`[...list]`) as to not mutate accidentally. You could just as well do `list.sort(...)` if you don't need or care about mutating.

```js
const list = [{
    key: "Name",
    textColor: "red"
  },{
    key: "Age",
    textColor: "green"
  },{
    key: "Occupation",
    textColor: "yellow"
}]

const newOrder = ["Occupation", "Name", "Age"]

function sort(list, order) {
  return [...list].sort((a, b) => {
    const keyIndexA = order.indexOf(a.key);
    const keyIndexB = order.indexOf(b.key);
    if (keyIndexA < keyIndexB) return -1;
    if (keyIndexA > keyIndexB) return 1;
    return 0;
  });
}

console.log(sort(list, newOrder));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use just regular [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
const list = [{key: "Name",textColor: "red"},{key: "Age",textColor: "green"},{key: "Occupation",textColor: "yellow"}];
const newOrder = ["Occupation", "Name", "Age"];

const result = list.sort(({key: a}, {key: b}) => newOrder.indexOf(a) - newOrder.indexOf(b));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Comment: note that sort do the in place sorting, no need to assign to new variable

Answer (score 0):

You can try to loop through the `newOrder` array, find the object that correlates to the first item and push to a new array.

```
const orderedList = [];
newOrder.forEach(order => {
    orderedList.push(list.find(({key}) => key === order));
})
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use [orderBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy) from lodash library